# How to reduce space between Items in horizontal Flatlist

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, native-base

I use horizontal  FlatList of React native and use ListItem and Card of Native base in it to render my List Items.
It works but the space between items is too big and I can't reduce it.

this is FlatList :

```
<FlatList
   horizontal data={this.props.data}
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
   keyExtractor={item => item.title}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
 />
```

and this is renderItem:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
      return (
        <ListItem onPress={() => 
                 this.props.navigate(this.state.navigateTO,{
                    id:item['id'],
                    title:item['title'],
                    top_image:item['top_image'],
                    token:this.state.token,
                    lan:this.state.lan,
                    type:this.state.type,
                 }
                  )} >
          <Card style={{height:320, width: 200}}>
              <CardItem  cardBody>
                 <Image source={{uri:item['top_image']}}
                 style={{height:200, width: 200}}/>
              </CardItem>
              <CardItem>
                <Left>
                  <Body>
                  <Text >{item['title']}</Text>
                  <Text note>{item['city']} </Text>
                </Body>
              </Left>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
       </ListItem>
      );
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried defining a custom `ItemSeparatorComponent` and passing it as FlatList prop?

Comment: how can reduce space with use ItemSeparatorComponent ?! I believe its used for increase space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the `ListItem` that you have wrapped the `Card` in that is causing the massive padding that you are seeing. If you remove that you will find that the cards are much closer together.

You could then wrap the card in a `TouchableOpacity` component, or similar, that would allow you to have your touch event and it would also allow you more control over the space of the items by adjusting the styling on the `TouchableOpacity`.

Remember to import it

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

This is how you could update your `renderItem`

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
      this.props.navigate(this.state.navigateTO,{
          id:item['id'],
          title:item['title'],
          top_image:item['top_image'],
          token:this.state.token,
          lan:this.state.lan,
          type:this.state.type,
          }
      )} 
      style={{ padding: 10 }} // adjust the styles to suit your needs
      >
      <Card style={{height:320, width: 200}}>
          <CardItem  cardBody>
              <View
              style={{height:200, width: 200, backgroundColor:'green'}}/>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem>
            <Left>
              <Body>
              <Text >{item['title']}</Text>
              <Text note>{item['city']}</Text>
            </Body>
          </Left>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank's, this is work for remove space but when scroll on the list, items highlight when touched. is there any way to disable this effect?

Comment: Use a different touchable. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches#touchables

Comment: thanks.I  use **TouchableWithoutFeedback** and work well.